# Comparing strings between files with awk, when the strings use special characters

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files, and I'm trying to find if the strings from file1 are in file2. Each file has only one string per line. In principle something simple like grep -f should work, but I think the fact that the strings are complex is causing problems. This is an example of how the strings look like:

file1:

```
InChI=1S/C33H29N3O12S.4K/c1-18-6-7-22(35(14-28(37)38)15-29(39)40)25(10-18)46-8-9-47-26-12-19-11-20(32-34-21-4-2-3-5-27(21)49-32)33(45)48-24(19)13-23(26)36(16-30(41)42)17-31(43)44;;;;/h2-7,10-13H,8-9,14-17H2,1H3,(H,37,38)(H,39,40)(H,41,42)(H,43,44);;;;/q;4*+1/p-4
```

File2:

```
InChI=1S/C33H29N3O12S.4K/c1-18-6-7-22(35(14-28(37)38)15-29(39)40)25(10-18)46-8-9-47-26-12-19-11-20(32-34-21-4-2-3-5-27(21)49-32)33(45)48-24(19)13-23(26)36(16-30(41)42)17-31(43)44;;;;/h2-7,10-13H,8-9,14-17H2,1H3,(H,37,38)(H,39,40)(H,41,42)(H,43,44);;;;/q;4*+1/p-4

InChI=1S/C16H24O2/c1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16(17)18/h2-8,13-15H2,1H3,(H,17,18)

InChI=1S/C11H23O5P/c12-11(13)9-7-5-3-1-2-4-6-8-10-17(14,15)16/h1-10H2,(H,12,13)(H2,14,15,16)
```

In this case, both first lines match, and the others don't. In the actual case there's ~200 lines in `file1`, and ~10K in `file2`.

My attempt so far is something like:

```
awk 'NR=FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' file1 file2 > file3.out
```

Which works for simple test files, but not for the actual files.

Comment: based solely on the small sample of data provided: `grep -Ff f1 f2` finds the single line match

Comment: if you wish to stick with `awk`, 2x issues to address ... `NR=FNR` is an assigment but what you want is a comparison => `NR==FNR` ... `!($1 in a)` says to print the line if it's **not** in the array but what you want is to print if the line **is** in the array; net result: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a)' f1 f2`

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is the grep `-F` option.  Without it, the lines in the `-f filename` are regular expressions.  They're *patterns*, not strings.

In your example, the `4*` sequence means "zero or more occurrences of `4`", definitely not what you meant!

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that the problem was something with the windows encoding on a unix system, when I just copied the pure text into a unix terminal, grep -Ff worked fine